# How to pass a list of Objects to a method type object

Tags: java

My code is as follows:

I have a class of shape:

```
public class shape{

  private int x;
  private int y;
  ...
```

Then I have an interface:

```
public interface PredicatesSet<T> {...
```

And a class that implements it:

```
public class Predicates implements PredicatesSet<shape> {
     ...
     public void remove(Predictor pred) {
     ...
```

Now, in my main method I create a list of shapes and I want that method in Predicates to remove some of them based on the value in `Predictor pred`

I can't figure out how to pass the list to the remove method.

Comment: You don't have to do all this, because Java already has a Predicate interface, and Collection already has a removeIf() method taking a Predicate as argument. You should also respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: I have more custom methods...

Comment: Then ask about them. That said, how to pass a list to a method is by adding an argument of type list to that method.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't... its a part of a home assignment

Comment: /*
  *  Remove every object, obj, for which pred.test(obj) is true.
  */
 public void remove(Predictor pred);

Comment: Then ask your teacher. You can't possible act on a List if you don't have a reference to that list. And your question and code is much too vague to understand what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145810/discussion-between-ofer-orgal-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: No. Clarify your question instead.

Comment: It looks like you needn't pass a list to the method, because a collection to remove from is gonna be a private field and you will get the access to it inside the method.

Comment: But the shape and predictions object are not the same